# Use `trace` to skip a line in an R function

Tags: r, debugging, trace

Assume I have a function where I want to tweak the behavior a little bit (skip a certain line, say). I could

1. Copy & paste the function and change it.
2. Use `debug` to change the code interactively.
3. Use `trace` to inject own code.

I am **only** interested in Option 3. for this post.

For instance, let's assume the following very simple code:

```r
f <- function(dbg) {
  x <- rnorm(1)
  if (dbg) {
     cat("Message 1\n")
  }
  if (x < 0 & dbg) {
     cat("Message 2\n")
  } 
  x
}
```

If (for whatever reason) I want to skip `Message 2` (but keep `Message 1`) I could use `trace` as follows:

```r
set.seed(12231)
untrace(f)
f(TRUE)
# Message 1
# Message 2
# [1] -0.5787277

trace(f, quote(dbg <- FALSE), at = 4, print = FALSE)
set.seed(12231)
f(TRUE)
# Message 1
# [1] -0.5787277
```

Now assume a slightly different function `g`:

```r
g <- function() {
  x <- rnorm(1)
  cat("Message\n")
  cat("Message 2\n")
  x
}
```

*Conceptually* I would like to do something like:

```r
trace(g, quote(if(FALSE)), at = 4, print = FALSE)
```

but this does not work obviously.

Is there a way how I could use `trace` to skip (a) certain line(s)? Or is my only option to copy, paste and edit the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively all `trace` does (for regular functions) is insert a call to `.doTrace` at the desired point inside the function body. We can do the same manually to achieve the exact same effect.

But in your case we want to *remove* instead of add; and we can do this as well:

```
modified_body <- body(g)
modified_body[4] <- NULL

original_body <- body(g)
body(g) <- modified_body

g()

# “untrace”:
body(g) <- original_body
```

---

I tried getting this to work with `trace`, by passing the modified body as the `tracer`. Unfortunately I cannot prevent the original function from executing afterwards: adding an explicit `return()` call to the `tracer` does nothing (since `.doTrace` uses `eval.parent` to evaluate the `tracer` code, and `return` inside `eval` does not exit the calling scope). I *can* use `stop()` instead of `return()`. However, this is undesirable since it always drops to the *top level* rather than to the caller of `g`. I tried to influence this by installing a `globalCallingHandler` but there is no appropriate restart I could invoke, and at any rate regular restarts would drop us right back into `g` rather than its caller.

I don’t know if this could be circumvented even in principle: it would essentially require modifying the active call stack — which restarts *do*, but only in very limited ways as far as I know (namely, by dropping the *entire* call stack via the `abort` restart, or by resuming inside the innermost call frame).

Comment: Very insightful. Building on your idea I think the most convenient way for me would be `body(g)[[4]] <- substitute(if(FALSE) { CC } , list(CC = body(g)[[4]]))`

Answer (score 2):

Here are several approaches.  All depend on redefining `cat` in some way.

**1) redefine cat as list** Redefine `cat` like this.  Add `print=FALSE` argument as in the question if you don't want the `Tracing` message.

```
trace(g, quote(cat <- list), at = 4)
## [1] "g"

g()
## Message
## Tracing g() step 4 
## [1] 0.6007088
```

**2) Check cat arg** Another way is:

```
trace(g, quote(cat <- \(x, ...) if (x != "Message 2\n") base::cat(x, ...)))
## [1] "g"

g()
## Tracing g() on entry 
## Message
## [1] 1.997213
```

**3) Count cat calls**  Set i to 0 and then update it each time `cat` is invoked.  Only carry it out if not the second time.

```
trace(g, quote({ i <- 0; cat <- \(...) if ((i <<- i + 1) != 2) base::cat(...)}))
## [1] "g"

g()
## Tracing g() on entry 
## Message
## [1] 0.6007088
```

Comment: Very creative way and totally makes sense to skip a single line +1. Any thoughts on how to extend the idea to skip more than one line though? Of course, we could use the same trick on each call but this could become very tedious.

Comment: Depending on the specific code it could be as easy as `f1 <- f2 <- f3 <- list`